# DllImport stuct parameters

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have 3 C++ structs as well as two methods and I want to use them via C#. Here is my C# code as well as few comments on the C++ code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct smat
{
    public long rows;
    public long cols;
    public long vals;     
    public long* pointr;  
    public long* rowind;  
    public double* value; 
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct dmat {
    long rows;
    long cols;
    double **value;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct svdrec {
    int d;      
    dmat Ut;    // it was dmat* in C++
    double *S;  
    dmat Vt;    // it was dmat* in C++
};

[DllImport(@"file.dll", EntryPoint = "svdNewSMat", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern smat svdNewSMat(int rows, int cols, int vals); // it was smat* in C++

[DllImport(@"file.dll", EntryPoint = "svdLAS2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern svdrec svdLAS2(smat a, long dimensions, long iterations, double[] las2end, double kappa); // it was smat* and svdrec* in C++
```

**EDIT:**
Here are the C++ headers

```
typedef struct smat *SMat;
typedef struct dmat *DMat;
typedef struct svdrec *SVDRec;

/* Harwell-Boeing sparse matrix. */
struct smat {
  long rows;
  long cols;
  long vals;     /* Total non-zero entries. */
  long *pointr;  /* For each col (plus 1), index of first non-zero entry. */
  long *rowind;  /* For each nz entry, the row index. */
  double *value; /* For each nz entry, the value. */
};

/* Row-major dense matrix.  Rows are consecutive vectors. */
struct dmat {
  long rows;
  long cols;
  double **value; /* Accessed by [row][col]. Free value[0] and value to free.*/
};

struct svdrec {
  int d;      /* Dimensionality (rank) */
  DMat Ut;    /* Transpose of left singular vectors. (d by m)
             The vectors are the rows of Ut. */
  double *S;  /* Array of singular values. (length d) */
  DMat Vt;    /* Transpose of right singular vectors. (d by n)
             The vectors are the rows of Vt. */
};

extern DMat svdNewDMat(int rows, int cols);
extern SVDRec svdLAS2(SMat A, long dimensions, long iterations, double end[2], 
                  double kappa);
```

**I am not giving the full code because It includes a lot of libraries.**
And here is what I excecute to test:

```
var a = svdNewSMat(3, 6, 3);
var m = new double[] {1, 2};
var r = svdLAS2(a, 1, 0, m, 1e-6); // I get the Exception here
```

The second line gives me *Attempted to read or write protected memory* error.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link may be helpful. Check out this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The code you post is pure declaration. There is no executable code here. And you didn't show the C++ declarations. Clearly you can't match a struct against a pointer (i.e. dmat* vs dmat). I'd probably look to wrap this with C++/CLI.

Comment: here, I updated my post, added more info...

Comment: And also the source is not mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply replace dmat* with dmat on the C# side. A pointer is not automatically marshalled as reference

Please look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0szztey7(v=vs.80).aspx on how to marshall embedded pointers correctly.

Comment: OK, so i need to rewrite everithing to IntPtr? But I am experiencing a problem with marshaling double[] {1, 2} for the second methods parameter..

Comment: If you struggling with all this marshalling. You should look at SWIG to do it all for you. http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html

Answer (score 1):

If it was smat* and dmat*, use IntPtr instead smad/dmat.

Comment: @DimitarVouldjeff It certainly is an improvement. There are just no doubt loads more errors in your code. Note that you showed so little code there is no way anyone could fix all your bugs.

Comment: i meant i still have an exception

Answer (score 1):

You can just use IntPtr if you're working with pointers from the DLL. Keeping in mind that a lot of boxing/unboxing will occur during this work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a c++ module can perform operations on a c# struct.

Try using a class instead of a struct.

Comment: I have them also declared in C++

Answer (score 0):

In function declarations, the pinvoke equivalent to pointer-to-pointer is usually `ref IntPtr`  In a struct declaration (and as others pointed out), it should be just `IntPtr`. Keep in mind that in function invocation, things are often more complicated than just getting your struct declarations correct (e.g. calling conventions may need to be modified).

Comment: So you suggest I replace IntPtr everywhere and ref IntPtr in the second method?

Comment: As I said, the answer isn't that simple necessarily. But generally,
a) you don't need 'unsafe', except in a few circumstances,
b) normally, any pointer in a struct maps to IntPtr

Your success may also depend on whether CDecl is a valid calling convention in this case, and/or proper population of the pointers (are they allocated prior to call? do they need to be? is it a global pointer? etc, etc.)